# Can Minor Conjuration be on my space?

Tags: dnd-5e, summoning

From the way I asked the question, it would seem to me that the answer is *yes*, because it can be on my hand. However, that's not really what I want.

My character is a just-over-3-foot currently 2nd-level wizard forest gnome. Therefore, I can make stuff with *Minor Conjuration* that can cover me up, like a bullet-shaped sort of dome made of steel. This would prevent any range damage once, and then disappear (if I understand correctly). I'm not yet sure of applications for this – maybe to prepare for an ambush, though in that case my question is unnecessary. A combat situation would be during a retreat –, but it doesn't matter much. What I was wondering was if I could do this – make a hard object that covers me, a 3-foot gnome – in a single action.

The way I thought to do this is to conjure the object already on top of me, but then it wouldn't be neither on my hand, nor on an unoccupied space within 10ft – it would be on *my* space. At first, I thought no, beause it specifies the object would have to appear *"in your hand or in an unoccupied space that you can see within 10 ft. of you"*. But then I thought it could just be DM ruling (my prevalent opinion right now), or maybe you could do a trick of making it appear "on your hand" and then pull your hand back before the weight of the cocoon smashes it against the ground.

Anyway, I'm not nearly sure enough to either side not to ask. This might be a dumm question, but I'm looking forward for an answer...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### As written, it can only be *in your hand*, or *in an unoccupied space*.

Minor Conjuration says:

> you can use your action to conjure up an inanimate object **in your hand** or **on the ground in an unoccupied space** that you can see within 10 feet of you.

So *rules as written*, these are the only two choices.

#### Ask your DM.

As a DM, with an ability like this, I may rule in favor of the player and their creativity. It doesn't hurt to *ask* your DM if a particular idea works, even if it goes against the strict RAW ruling on the ability.

Comment: Dex save to align yourself with the dropping cone!

Comment: Thanks! That's what I thought, but it's nice to know for sure. ;)

Comment: @NautArch except if you read the given description in the answer. It has to be **on the ground** So you cannot drop it onto yourself